# How to customize the re-direct page when a user tries to access a blocked site

Tags: proxy, squid, network-monitoring

How to customize the html page which is re-directed when a user tries to access a URL which has been blacklisted by squid proxy server.

```
acl blocksites url_regex "/etc/squid/squid-block.acl"
http_access deny blocksites
```

I would like to re-direct to a custom HTML page explaining why he is not allowed to go the blocked site or send him to an empty page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pages you are looking for are located in

```
/usr/share/squid/errors/{your language}
```

e.g. for English

```
/usr/share/squid/errors/en
```

Comment: will give this a try tomorrow

Comment: I see from another question that you're using squid on 2K3. The error pages are found in \squid\share\errors\{your language} e.g \squid\share\errors\English.